# Want my code to print only 2 decimal places

Tags: java

```
public class Exercise05_08 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Celsius\t\tFahrenheit\t|\tFahrenheit\tCelsius");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");

    double celsius = 40; double farenheit = 120;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; celsius--, farenheit -= 10, i++) {
      System.out.println(celsius + "\t\t" + celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius) + "\t|\t" +     farenheit + "\t\t" + fahrenheitToCelsius(farenheit));
    }
  }

  public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius) {
    return (9.0 / 5.0) * celsius + 32;
  }

  public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) {
    return (5.0 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);
  }
}
```

Some of the values print out with several decimal places and i want all of the values to print with just 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

You can have 2 decimal places using [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String output = myFormatter.format(value);
```

You can find additional information about custom formats and patterns construction (and how to use them) [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) method:

```
System.out.format("%.2f", celsius);
```

will format the value with 2 decimal places.

Since you are using println() you may want to include "\n" in the end of your format strings to insert a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change to not print only 2 digits after dot:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("%.2f");
String s = formatter.format(celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius));
```

And print:

```
System.out.println(celsius + "\t\t" + s + "\t|\t" + farenheit + "\t\t" + fahrenheitToCelsius(farenheit));
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy fix would be to multiply the outcome by 100, cast them to an int, then divide them by 100 again to a double.

It might not be the most elegant solution, but it would work..

EDIT: apparently there's a more elegant solution, so forget it.

Comment: No it doesn't. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java/12684082#12684082) for proof.